# how to afect jlabel by changing different combobox values

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I'm having some trouble using two comboboxes to affect the state of one item. Each combo box has a value between 1 and 99, I'm trying to change the values in each, combine them, then display this value on a jlabel. So far I can only the first combobox seems to impact the formula. I have simplified it to the following and thanks for any help :)

private int value1int, value2int;

```
    value1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() 
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ex) 
        {
            if (ex.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
            {
                // assume single selection
                int value1int = (Integer)ex.getItemSelectable().getSelectedObjects()[0];
            }
        }
    });

    value2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() 
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent exs) 
        {
            if (exs.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
            {
                // assume single selection
                int value2int = (Integer)exs.getItemSelectable().getSelectedObjects()[0];
            }
        }
    });


    overallValue2.setText((Integer.toString(value1int + value2int)));
    overallValue2.revalidate();
```

Comment: You're thinking procedurally.  You're working in a event driven environment, you need to code to respond to events...

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like that:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame ...

private int labelVal;

...


// combobox events - The same code to both comboboxes must works

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent exs) 
{
   if (exs.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
   {
       // assume single selection
       int aux = (Integer)combobox1.getSelectedItem()+(Integer)combobox2.getSelectedItem();
       int labelVal= aux;
   }
}
```

Them refresh the screen

Comment: This actually managed to work, however, I had to duplicate each item listener for each combobox. It works so thanks!